# How to write user input to a text file using fputs in C++

Tags: c++, int, user-input, text-files

I am not the best programmer with c++ but I am trying to learn. I am trying to take user input and write it into a text file (without overwriting the old one) but I can't figure out where to plugin the variable (int). Here is my code so far...

```
int main()
{
   int i;
  cout << "Please enter something: ";
  cin >> i;

   FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\test.txt","a");
  if (pFile!=NULL)

    fputs ("C++ Rocks!",pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Also, if there is a more effecient way of doing this, please let me know! This is just what I was able to find on the internet that *worked.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do:

```
{
  string i; // dont forget to #include <string>
  cout << "Please enter something: ";
  cin >> i;

  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\test.txt","a");
  if (pFile!=NULL)
  {
     fputs("C++ Rocks!", pFile);
     fputs(i.c_str(), pFile);
  }

  fclose (pFile);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that reads/writes an arbitrary string, while he probably wants to know how to output an integer.

Comment: Since he is writing to a TXT file, I don't think that matters. For what I understand, he wants the number written inside the file too, so why not just read it as a string?

Answer (score 2):

That's the C way. (You can use fprintf to output your integer in a formatted string)

You should learn about the C++ Standard Library fstream class that allows you to write to files the same way you are doing it with the standard output right now.

```
std::ofstream my_file("test.txt");
my_file << i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C++ I/O may actually be more efficient, at least in terms of programmer's effort, in this case, since it uses the same `operator<<` for strings, integers, and all other types that can be output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    // open the file in append mode
    std::ofstream pFile("C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\test.txt", std::ios::app);
    // append the string to the file
    pFile << "C++ Rocks!\n";

    // get a number from the user
    int i;
    std::cout << "Please enter something: ";
    std::cin >> i;
    // append the number to the file too
    pFile << i << '\n';
}
```