# How can I fix this error? "Method 'str' could not be resolved"

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, ostringstream

What is the meaning of this problem and how can I fix it?
It's look like it's not meet the function `str()` while I try to use it.
In fact, I want to take the "string" from `rhs` and to put it in `this->file`, so if you have alternative idea, it's good too.

> Method 'str' could not be resolved
>   Method 'c_str' could not be resolved

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyFile {
    FILE* file;
    MyFile& operator=(const MyFile& rhs) const;
    MyFile(const MyFile& rhs);
public:
    MyFile(const char* filename) :
            file(fopen(filename, "w")) {
        if (file == NULL) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }
    ~MyFile() {
        fclose(file);
    }

    template<typename T>
    MyFile& operator<<(const T& rhs) {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << rhs;
        if (std::fputs(ss.str().c_str(), this->file) == EOF) { // Method 'str' could not be resolved
            throw std::exception();
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Resolving `str()` works fine in https://godbolt.org/g/8KKrgh (after fixing the mistyped class name), but `std::fputs` expects a `char*`, not a `string`.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig And how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write user input to a text file using fputs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546725/how-to-write-user-input-to-a-text-file-using-fputs-in-c)

Comment: @NickyC I tried it : `if (std::fputs(ss.str().c_str(), this->file) == EOF)` and it's not working yet..

Comment: What is the error after you change to `if (std::fputs(ss.str().c_str(), this->file) == EOF)`?

Comment: @MartinZhai I edited my question - see now.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I test with visual studio and MingGW, both work after change to `if (std::fputs(ss.str().c_str(), this->file) == EOF)`.

Comment: @MartinZhai with eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `str()` is the function that cannot be resolved?
Instead, I assume `fputs()` cannot be resolved. The reason is that `fputs` expects a `const char*`, but you are giving it an `std::string` which is returned by `str()`.
Try `fputs(ss.str().c_str(), this->file)`.

Comment: Your updated code compiles just fine with gcc. Every standard-compliant compiler should be able to compile it...

Answer (score 0):

```
    std::ostringstream oss;
    FILE *file;
    std::string s = oss.str();
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::fputs(s.c_str(), file);
```

covert ostringstream  to std::string and than convert in const char *